# Is there an easier way for a multiple of if else questions?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a result produced based on 2 values that both are the result of formulas applied to multiple input fields.

I have succeeded somewhat in creating a multitude of if/else statements basically with the power of elimination of the smallest value first.

Now just this 'simple' if / else function is about 40~50 rows of code. and my lack of knowledge prevents me of finding a better solution. I hope someone could point me in a direction.

I've tried looking into selecting from an array but I don't feel this is the solution to my problem as there is not 1 value but 2 values are required.

```
if (document.getElementById('reserve').checked == false) {
      if (capaciteit_te < 1.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01) {
        document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp1
      } else {
        if (capaciteit_te < 2.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01) {
          document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp1
        } else {
          if (capaciteit_te < 3.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) {
            document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp1
          } else {
            if (capaciteit_te < 4.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 1.01) {
              document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp1
            } else {
              if (capaciteit_te < 1.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) {
                document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp2
              } else {
                if (capaciteit_te < 2.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) {
                  document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp2
                } else {
                  if (capaciteit_te < 3.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01) {
                    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp2
                  } else {
                    if (capaciteit_te < 3.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) {
                      document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp3
                    } else {
                      if (capaciteit_te < 4.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01) {
                        document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp2
                      } else {
                        if (capaciteit_te < 5.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01) {
                          document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp2
                        } else {
                          if (capaciteit_te < 6.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) {
                            document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp2
                          } else {
                            if (capaciteit_te < 5.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01) {
                              document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp3
                            } else {
                              if (capaciteit_te < 6.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01) {
                                document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp3
                              } else {
                                if (capaciteit_te < 8.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01) {
                                  document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp3
                                } else {
                                  if (capaciteit_te < 10.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01) {
                                    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp3
                                  } else {
                                    if (capaciteit_te < 11.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) {
                                      document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp3
                                    } else {
                                      if (capaciteit_te < 16.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) {
                                        document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp4
                                      } else {
                                        if (capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 1.01) {
                                          document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp4
                                        } else {
                                          if (capaciteit_te < 10.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01) {
                                            document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp5
                                          } else {
                                            if (capaciteit_te < 16.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01) {
                                              document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp5
                                            } else {
                                              if (capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) {
                                                document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp5
                                              }
                                              if (capaciteit_te < 6.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) {
                                                document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp6
                                              } else {
                                                if (capaciteit_te < 11.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01) {
                                                  document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp6
                                                } else {
                                                  if (capaciteit_te < 16.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01) {
                                                    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp6
                                                  } else {
                                                    if (capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01) {
                                                      document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp6
                                                    } else {
                                                      if (capaciteit_te < 18.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) {
                                                        document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp8
                                                      } else {
                                                        if (capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01) {
                                                          document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp8
                                                        } else {
                                                          if (capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) {
                                                            document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp12
                                                          } else {
                                                            document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = "Geen bijpassende pomp gevonden, meem contact met DAB op om te kijken welke pomp voor u geschikt is"
                                                          }
                                                        }
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              }
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = "Reserve pomp nog niet geimplementeerd"}
```

the function works but I want a different approach

Comment: How about using Switch instead?

Comment: this somewhat looks like `callback hell` :p

Comment: `switch` would be useless here.

Comment: It doesn't have to be nested. You could do `if() - else if()- else if`  without the nesting

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an array for your 3 "values" and iterate over it.
The following is an example, hopefully it's clear.

```js
const capaciteit_te = 0.5;
const max_opvoer_clc = 2.5;

const a = [
  [ 1.01, 4.01, "pomp1" ],
  [ 2.01, 3.01, "pomp1" ],
  [ 3.01, 2.01, "pomp1" ],
  [ 4.01, 1.01, "pomp1" ],
  [ 1.01, 6.01, "pomp2" ]
];

let found = false;

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  const b = a[i];
  if (capaciteit_te < b[0] && max_opvoer_clc < b[1]) {
    console.log(b[2]);
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (!found) {
  console.log("not found!");
}
```

Comment: But for `pomp1`, multiple ranges are possible.

Comment: This is just an example. The array should be built based on the if else. I wrote only 2 random entries.

Comment: Ah, okay. I assumed, this would be one entry per `pomp` value

Comment: No problem. I have updated the example and added more entries to the array.

Comment: Answer seems to be the best so far since it actually provides a decision map to follow.

Comment: This is for sure the best provided answer I've seen. This allows flexibility, as well as being much cleaner than the original.

Comment: This suits my needs perfectly!

Just to be sure I understande the code. (that's more important to me then to get it working) with the b[0] and b[1] you tell the code to compaire the value to array 0 and 1 in the const a? and with the a[i] bit you let it cycle through all the brackets?

Comment: Correct it's a 2d array. b (a[i]) is a 1d array for each "if" also b[2] is the HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

One option, to at least make it better, is to split finding the prompt and doing the DOM interaction (setting the element)

Like this:

```js
function findAdvies(capaciteit_te, max_opvoer_clc) {
    if (capaciteit_te < 1.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01)
        return pomp1
    if (capaciteit_te < 2.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01)
        return pomp1
    if (capaciteit_te < 3.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01)
        return pomp1
    if (capaciteit_te < 4.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 1.01)
        return pomp1
    if (capaciteit_te < 1.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01)
        return pomp2
    if (capaciteit_te < 2.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01)
        return pomp2
    if (capaciteit_te < 3.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01)
        return pomp2
    if (capaciteit_te < 3.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01)
        return pomp3
    if (capaciteit_te < 4.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01)
        return pomp2
    if (capaciteit_te < 5.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01)
        return pomp2
    if (capaciteit_te < 6.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01)
        return pomp2
    if (capaciteit_te < 5.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01)
        return pomp3
    if (capaciteit_te < 6.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01)
        return pomp3
    if (capaciteit_te < 8.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01)
        return pomp3
    if (capaciteit_te < 10.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01)
        return pomp3
    if (capaciteit_te < 11.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01)
        return pomp3
    if (capaciteit_te < 16.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01)
        return pomp4
    if (capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 1.01)
        return pomp4
    if (capaciteit_te < 10.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01)
        return pomp5
    if (capaciteit_te < 16.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01)
        return pomp5
    if (capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01)
        return pomp5
    if (capaciteit_te < 6.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01)
        return pomp6
    if (capaciteit_te < 11.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01)
        return pomp6
    if (capaciteit_te < 16.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01)
        return pomp6
    if (capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01)
        return pomp6
    if (capaciteit_te < 18.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01)
        return pomp8
    if (capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01)
        return pomp8
    if (capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01)
        return pomp12

    return "Geen bijpassende pomp gevonden, meem contact met DAB op om te kijken welke pomp voor u geschikt is"
}
```

and

```js
if (document.getElementById('reserve').checked == false) {
    var advies = findAdvies(capaciteit_te, max_opvoer_clc);
    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = advies;
}
```

Because we `return` early, we don't need the nesting or even the braces :)

Next step is to make "findAdvies" easier/shorter - but that's a bit hard without more domain knowledge (without reserve engineering)

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be:

```
if (document.getElementById('reserve').checked == false) {
if (capaciteit_te < 1.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 2.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 3.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 4.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 1.01) {
    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp1;
}
else if (capaciteit_te < 1.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 2.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 3.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 4.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 5.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 6.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) {
    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp2;
}
else if (capaciteit_te < 3.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 5.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 6.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 8.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 10.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 11.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) {
    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp3;
}
else if (capaciteit_te < 16.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 1.01) {
    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp4;
}
else if (capaciteit_te < 10.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 16.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) {
    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp5;
}
else if (capaciteit_te < 6.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 11.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 16.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 4.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 3.01) {
    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp6;
}
else if (capaciteit_te < 18.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01 ||
    capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 5.01) {
    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp8;
}
else if (capaciteit_te < 20.01 && max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) {
    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp12;
}
else {
    document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = "Geen bijpassende pomp gevonden, meem contact met DAB op om te kijken welke pomp voor u geschikt is"
}
} else { document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = "Reserve pomp nog niet geimplementeerd" }
```

Answer (score 1):

The sum of extreme values for `capaciteit_te` and `max_opvoer_clc` seem to be constant per `pomp` value. You could check for the extreme range for these 2 variables AND the **sum** of 2 values to be less than the maximum range like this. This would need only one `if()` condition block per `pomp` value.

```
if (capaciteit_te < 4.01 &&
   max_opvoer_clc < 4.01 &&
   (capaciteit_te + max_opvoer_clc) < 5.02) 
{
   document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp1
} 
else if (capaciteit_te < 3.01 &&
   max_opvoer_clc < 6.01 &&
   (capaciteit_te + max_opvoer_clc) < 8.02) 
{
   document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp2
} 
else if (capaciteit_te < 11.01 &&
   max_opvoer_clc < 5.01 &&
   (capaciteit_te + max_opvoer_clc) < 13.02) 
{
   document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = pomp3
}
//similar conditions for pomp4, pomp5 etc
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a linear approach by using a function with early return and checking the `capaciteit_te` first and the the various values of `max_opvoer_clc`.

After calling the function replace `undefined` with an approapriate text.

The advantage of this approach is the easy maintanability.

```
function check() {
    if (capaciteit_te < 1.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 4.01) return pomp1;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) return pomp2;
        return;
    }
    if (capaciteit_te < 2.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 3.01) return pomp1;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) return pomp2;
        return;
    }
    if (capaciteit_te < 3.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) return pomp1;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 5.01) return pomp2;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) return pomp3;
        return;
    }
    if (capaciteit_te < 4.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 1.01) return pomp1;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 4.01) return pomp2;
        return;
    }
    if (capaciteit_te < 5.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 3.01) return pomp2;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 5.01) return pomp3;
        return;
    }
    if (capaciteit_te < 6.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) return pomp2;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 5.01) return pomp3;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) return pomp6;
        return;
    }
    if (capaciteit_te < 8.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 4.01) return pomp3;
        return;
    }
    if (capaciteit_te < 10.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 3.01) return pomp3;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 4.01) return pomp5;
        return;
    }
    if (capaciteit_te < 11.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) return pomp3;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 5.01) return pomp6;
        return;
    }
    if (capaciteit_te < 16.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) return pomp4;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 3.01) return pomp5;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 4.01) return pomp6;
        return;
    }
    if (capaciteit_te < 18.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) return pomp8;
        return;
    }
    if (capaciteit_te < 20.01) {
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 1.01) return pomp4;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 2.01) return pomp5;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 3.01) return pomp6;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 5.01) return pomp8;
        if (max_opvoer_clc < 6.01) return pomp12;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like how this is written. am I correct to say that after the semicolon ; the 2nd if is kind of the same as an else? like if it doesn't match the first one it goes to the second one to see if it can resolve the first if with a return?

Comment: right. the `return` statement terminates the function and any other flow is like an `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a pattern, or rather, two patterns. This should give the same output as your if-elses:

```
const simpleSum = capaciteit_te + max_opvoer_clc;
const complicatedSum = capaciteit_te + 4 * max_opvoer_clc;
const advies = document.getElementById('advies');

if (simpleSum < 5.02) {
    advies.innerHTML = pomp1;
} else if (simpleSum < 8.02) {
    advies.innerHTML = pomp2;
} else if (simpleSum < 13.02) {
    advies.innerHTML = pomp2;
} else if (complicatedSum < 24.09) {
    advies.innerHTML = pomp4;
} else if (complicatedSum < 28.09) {
    advies.innerHTML = pomp5;
} else if (complicatedSum < 32.09) {
    advies.innerHTML = pomp6;
} else if (complicatedSum < 42.09) {
    advies.innerHTML = pomp8;
} else if (complicatedSum < 44.09) {
    advies.innerHTML = pomp8;
} else // the "not found" message
```

If I didn't make mistake anywhere (and there's a very good chance that I did).

Generally: putting the business logic (which I had to reverse engineer and guess) into the code, that formula or formulas that stand behind generating the ifs, should be better than the original 28 separate ifs.

Comment: it is really close though not quite there. the absolute values are taken from a crosstab table 
<code>
2| 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 
1| 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 
------------------------------------------------- 
0| 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
</code>
if that makes sence as an example. if you have 7,1 with 7 as capaciteit_te and max_opvoer_clc as 1 the sum would be 8 thus pump 2 would be the advise, however pump 2 has the max value of 6 on capaciteit_te and be under performing.... this makes it quite tricky..

for some reason it won't allow me to change the crosstable to a codeblock

Answer (score 0):

Based on Tomer's suggestion

```
   const a = [
  [1.01, 4.01, pomp1],
  [2.01, 3.01, pomp1],
  [3.01, 2.01, pomp1],
  [4.01, 1.01, pomp1],
  [1.01, 6.01, pomp2],
  [2.01, 6.01, pomp2],
  [3.01, 5.01, pomp2],
  [4.01, 4.01, pomp2],
  [5.01, 3.01, pomp2],
  [6.01, 2.01, pomp2],
  [3.01, 6.01, pomp3],
  [6.01, 5.01, pomp3],
  [8.01, 4.01, pomp3],
  [10.01, 3.01, pomp3],
  [11.01, 2.01, pomp3],
  [16.01, 2.01, pomp4],
  [20.01, 1.01, pomp4],
  [10.01, 4.01, pomp5],
  [16.01, 3.01, pomp5],
  [20.01, 2.01, pomp5],
  [6.01, 6.01, pomp6],
  [11.01, 5.01, pomp6],
  [16.01, 4.01, pomp6],
  [20.01, 3.01, pomp6],
  [18.01, 6.01, pomp8],
  [20.01, 5.01, pomp8],
  [20.01, 6.01, pomp12],
];

const b = [
  [2.01, 6.01, pomp3],
  [3.01, 5.01, pomp3],
  [4.01, 4.01, pomp3],
  [5.01, 3.01, pomp3],
  [6.01, 2.01, pomp3],
  [9.01, 2.01, pomp4],
  [11.01, 1.01, pomp4],
  [5.01, 4.01, pomp5],
  [8.01, 3.01, pomp5],
  [10.01, 2.01, pomp5],
  [3.01, 6.01, pomp6],
  [6.01, 5.01, pomp6],
  [8.01, 4.01, pomp6],
  [10.01, 3.01, pomp6],
  [11.01, 2.01, pomp6],
  [9.01, 6.01, pomp8],
  [10.01, 5.01, pomp8],
  [11.01, 4.01, pomp8],
  [16.01, 2.01, pomp9],
  [20.01, 1.01, pomp9],
  [16.01, 3.01, pomp10],
  [12.01, 5.01, pomp11],
  [16.01, 4.01, pomp11],
  [20.01, 3.01, pomp11],
  [17.01, 6.01, pomp12],
  [20.01, 5.01, pomp12],
  [20.01, 6.01, pomp13],
];

let found = false;
if (document.getElementById('reserve').checked == false) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    const c = a[i];
    if (capaciteit_te < c[0] && max_opvoer_clc < c[1]) {
      document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = c[2];
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

} else {
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    const c = b[i];
    if (capaciteit_te < c[0] && max_opvoer_clc < c[1]) {
      document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = c[2];
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}

if (!found) {
  document.getElementById('advies').innerHTML = "niets gevonden"
}
```

This is perfect as it allows for easy modification if additional 'pompen' need to be added. Thank you tomer